# pruning tree with caret library returns complex trees

Tags: r, tree, machine-learning, r-caret, rpart

I'm using the caret package for a tree model. I understood that caret uses CV to find the optimal tuning parameter  for pruning the tree.

This is the code I use:

```
id2 <- sample(1:nrow(data),2/3*nrow(data))
#learn
app <- data[id2,]
#test
test <- data[-id2,]

ctrl<-trainControl(method="cv", number=8,classProbs=TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)
mod0 <- train(class~., data=app,method="rpart",trControl=ctrl,metric="ROC")
plot(mod0)
plot(mod0$finalModel,uniform=TRUE,margin=.1);text(mod0$finalModel,cex=0.8)
```

Here is my data:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xrCXTLqKvGiGeo2X0Y1DvoSKvzbYFnyccLimceDIbZg

But everytime I run the code I get trees of different complexities (because of CV?) and the tree is not really pruned but very complex and a lot of terminal nodes.

How can I get a less complex tree ?

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Comment: Are you the author of the library? I sent you an email.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the seed prior to calling `train` to get reproducible results. Also, if you are running in parallel, set the `seeds` option in `trainControl`.

As for "complex trees"... that is pretty subjective. Why do you expect them to be more simplistic?

One difference between the results of `train` and `rpart` is that the latter uses the "one SE" method for pruning while `train` prunes to the depth with the best performance. You can use a "one SE" method with `train` too (see the package website) but I've always found that it tends to be conservative (which was the original point).

Max